# What is wrong with this c++ code in giving a segmentation fault?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iterator>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main (void)
{
    int z,foo,t,n,k,i;
    cin>>t;
    while (t--)
    {
         vector<int> a;
         vector<int> b;
         cin>>n>>k;
         z = n;
         while (z--)
         {
            cin>>foo;
            a.push_back(foo);
         }
         sort(a.begin(),a.end());
         vector<int>::iterator it = a.begin();
         vector<int>::iterator bt = a.begin();
         while (bt != a.end())
         {
            bt = bt + (k-1);
            foo = *bt - *it;
            b.push_back(foo);
            it++;
         }
         sort(b.begin(),b.end());
         cout<<b[0]<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This code accepts the number of test cases, and then accepts two numbers, then takes the total number of numbers, and sorts them, takes their difference on the basis of `k` and sorts them, copies in a new vector and sorts them and outputs a new element.

The above code gives a segmentation fault.

Comment: What are you entering as `k`? Where is the guarantee that `bt = bt + (k-1)` does not sent `bt` out of range?

Comment: Have you run the code in a debugger to find out where the crash is occurring?

Comment: `k` will always be an integer like `1 2 3` and will always be less than `n`.

Comment: The first thing that's wrong with this code is that it's utterly unreadable. It's hard to tell what it's supposed to do without the help of meaningful identifiers. The second thing that's wrong is that it's not self-contained. It needs an input file which us not provided.

Comment: @sameer: "Less than n" is not enough. What makes you think that by doing `bt = bt + (k-1)` you will eventually hit `a.end()` exactly?

Comment: Compile with all warnings and debug info (`g++ -Wall -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: Use a debugger to find out where the program crashes. Examine variables at the time of the crash to find out why it crashes.

Comment: @sameer: Give me an example of `n` and `k` that causes the crash.

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem. The one that you mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are moving `bt` by `k - 1` steps on each iteration of the cycle

```
bt = bt + (k-1);
```

The initial value of `bt` is `a.begin()` and the cycle continuation condition is `bt != a.end()`. If the size of `a` (i.e. `n`) is not divisible by `k - 1`, `bt` will never be equal to `a.end()` and the cycle will never properly terminate. It will push `bt` out of valid range.

At that point the behavior will be undefined. The code will typically crash.